# Centering the content in the footer when resizing the browser window

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am building a website using wordpress theme. I have two elements (one floated left, second floated right) in the footer. I need to make it centered (the second one below the first one) when I resize the browser window. I guess I need to set `float:none;` in the media queries and center it somehow, but I wasn't able to figure it out.

[WEBPAGE LINK](http://svycarsky-dum-responsive.geneweb.cz/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="site-info">
      <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 75%;">
        <p style="float:left;">&copy; Copyright <?= date('Y'); ?> Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
        <div style="float:right;">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
          <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" /></a>
          <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- .site-info -->
```

I attach a picture so you could look at how I want it to look like when you resize the window under 800px.[image: PICTURE]

Comment: You really should separate the CSS out into a dedicated file and only use classes (and ids if necessary) to assign the appropriate values to each layer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove float position as shown below

```
 <div class="site-info">
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 75%;">
    <p >&copy; Copyright <?= date('Y'); ?> Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
    <div >Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
      <a style="display: block;  margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" /></a>
      <a style="display: block;  margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- .site-info -->
```

You can use @media screen in your css file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
.class_name {
    float:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do I select both <div> abd <p> tags and delete float on them in media queries? @Binoy Chacko

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do the CSS for your HTML when removing the floats for anything under 800px:
Your code:

```
<div class="site-info">
  <div style="margin:0 auto; width: 75%;">
    <p style="float:left;">&copy; Copyright <?= date('Y'); ?> Hotel Švýcarský Dům</p>
    <div style="float:right;">Naleznete nás na sociálních sítích: 
      <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 0 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/gplus.png" /></a>
      <a style="display: block; float:right; margin:-4px 5px 0 5px;" href=""><img src="/wp-content/themes/adamos/images/facebook.png" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div><!-- .site-info -->
```

Here's the media query that I would use to remove those two floats:
(Just put it in your CSS file at the bottom of all of your CSS)

```
@media all and (max-width:799px) 
{
    .site-info > div p, .site-info > div > div { float:none; }
}
```

That will remove the floats on both the p and the div when the viewport is under 800px.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help :/ @Gordon Smith

Comment: If you think it is a targeting issue, you could always give the 'p' tag and the 'div' tag class names, then you would simply change the line '.site-info > div p, .site-info > div > div { float:none; }' to .class-name-one, .class-name-two { float:none; }